# How to make a javascript horizontal accordion from collapsible panels

Tags: jquery, accordion, panel

Tying to make a horizontal accordion with collapsible panels and jquery. I don't want to use YUI ( its too heavy).

I can't use the accordion, for a few reasons...

Any pointers to tutorials on horizontal collapsible panels or show me how ?

thanks

Comment: http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/horizontal-javascript-accordion-menu/

Comment: @benedict_w  Awesome just perfect !!!